# What it is the proper syntax for opening multiple ports in security group with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to open multiple ports for EC2 instances within a security group using CloudFormation. However, I can't find documentation for proper syntax for doing so (opening multiple ports). Would something like the following work?

```
"InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
"Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
"Properties" : {
  "GroupDescription" : "Web Security Group",
  "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
     "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
     "FromPort" : "22",
     "ToPort" : "22",
     "FromPort" : "80",
     "ToPort" : "80",
     "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
  } ]
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a list. So add one more to that list.

```
 "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
  {
     "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
     "FromPort" : "22",
     "ToPort" : "22",
     "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
  },
  {
     "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
     "FromPort" : "80",
     "ToPort" : "80",
     "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
  }
 ]
```

Comment: Easy enough.. Thanks, helloV.

Answer (score 5):

And the equivalent in yaml

```
SecurityGroupIngress:
- IpProtocol: tcp
FromPort: 80
ToPort: 80
CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
- IpProtocol: tcp
FromPort: 443
ToPort: 443
CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```